# "Selectable" Select Elements within CKEditor4

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, ckeditor4.x

inserting `<select name='xy'><option value'1'>1</option></select>` elements within CKEditor4 (over insetHTML oder setData Function) makes them "unselectable", default behaviour is getting cut, so you could edit them with installed plugins (like default option, the options themself, name, etc....)
But i want the "default" behaviour. A Select Element with which you can select ;-)
If i Wrap the `<select>`

within `<span contendeditable="false">`, you could select elements but the selected='selected' attribute of the options are not updated.

Goal is to have the editor with editable text and selectable Select Elements, so i can read the HTML from the editor with the currenty selected option and write this to a PDF..

I tried to add my own eventListener to the select but this didn't work either.

Is there any "easy" mode to achieve this?

(Same Problem with checkboxes)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that browsers don't update "selected" attribute on changing the selected option.
Now i'm Iterating through the select elements, removing selected attribute for all options and addding it for the option which is selected. So if i get the Data from CKEditor i'll get the right option with `<option value"xy" selected="selected>xy</option>`

```
let elements = document.$.getElementsByClassName('Editor-Selector');

for (var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    let element = elements[i];
    let selectedOption = element.value;
    let options = element.options;
    for (var y = 0; y<options.length; y++) {
        let option = options[y];
        option.removeAttribute("selected");
        if (option.value == selectedOption) {
            option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
        }
    }
}
```